# Laravel Passport auth:api middleware results in  Route [login] not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have been keeping on getting  Route [login] not defined when I **try** do an HTTP post to the **API\Usercontroller@details**

I'm not sure why this is happening as when I look it up nothing related to this issue shows up.

I have been following this tutorial: https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

I have followed the installation guide from https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport

**THE RESULT I WANT**

[image]

**WHAT I GOT INSTEAD**

[image]

api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('login', 'API\UserController@login');
Route::post('register', 'API\UserController@register');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details');
});
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public $successStatus = 200;

    public function login()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]); 

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
        }

        if (Auth::attempt($validator->valid())) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
        }

        $input = $validator->valid();
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
        $user = User::create($input);
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
        $success['name'] = $user->name;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }

    public function details() 
    { 
        return response()->json(['success' => Auth::user()], $this-> successStatus); 
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required',
            'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
        ];
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I am **more** than happy to say that I have solved this myself.

It turns out Postman overwrote the Authorization parameter in this screenshot below (already added the token).

The tab was just hidden

[image]